# formatting phone number into a 10 digit number (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, format

Most phone numbers are formatted like this as your standard 10 digit north american phone number: 9759542606.

However, some are formatted like this:

```
(914) 552-7479 or 13105675417 (11 digits)
```

How do I write a query that converts these numbers into a 10 digit number with has no spaces or non-numeric characters? And if it's not possible, how would I do this in a spreadsheet?

Comment: If you're willing to add some additional software, lib_mysqludf_preg has a `PREG_REPLACE` function that will do the trick nicely.  I don't know if the tokens work or not but "\D" is the regex token for a non-digit.  https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()`.  This requires knowing the characters you don't want, but something like this:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(num, ' ', ''), '-', ''), ')', ''), '(', '')
```